# Getting wrong results from CUDA matrix multiplication kernel

Tags: cuda

I am new to CUDA. I have a kernel to do matrix multiplication. It seems alright for me but it is failing in some cases. Please help me where the problem is.

```
__global__ void matrixMultiply(float * A, float * B, float * C,
        int numARows, int numAColumns,
        int numBRows, int numBColumns,
        int numCRows, int numCColumns) 
{
    //@@ Insert code to implement matrix multiplication here

    int Row = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int Col = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    if (numAColumns != numBRows) return;

    if ((Row < numARows) && (Col < numBColumns)){
        float Cvalue = 0;

        for (int k = 0 ; k < numAColumns ; ++k )
            Cvalue += A[Row*numAColumns + k] * B[k * numBColumns + Col];

        C[Row*numCColumns + Col] = Cvalue;
        __syncthreads();
    }
}
```

I am invoking the kernel as follows.

```
int BLOCKX = (int)(ceil((numCRows / 8.0)));
int BLOCKY = (int)(ceil((numCColumns / 8.0)));
printf("Number of blocks: %d\t%d\n", BLOCKX, BLOCKY);
dim3 DimGrid(BLOCKX, BLOCKY);
dim3 DimBlock(8 , 8, 1);
```

Comment: Please pay more attention to code formatting in the future. You have a completely unnecessary `__syncthreads()` call in the kernel which is serving no purpose except to break your kernel. Furthermore, these coursera cuda questions are getting pretty repetitious, and I am voting to close this as a duplicate. If you are going to cheat on your coursework, at least check no one has already come here and cheated on the same assignment before you.

Comment: Mr. talnmies, I am not here to cheat myself. I need help because I tried hard and could not find where the problem is. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Your code will deadlock in the below :

```
  if ((Row < numARows) && (Col < numBColumns)){
            float Cvalue = 0;

            for (int k = 0 ; k < numAColumns ; ++k )
                Cvalue += A[Row*numAColumns + k] * B[k * numBColumns + Col];

            C[Row*numCColumns + Col] = Cvalue;
            __syncthreads();
        }
```

Consider a block where for some threads, the condition is satisfied, while for some it is not. In that case, this will deadlock. Put `__syncthreads()` outside the `if` conditions

Also replace `dim3 DimGrid(BLOCKX, BLOCKY);` by `dim3 DimGrid(BLOCKY, BLOCKX);`. That should fix it

Comment: The `__syncthreads()` serves absolutely no useful purpose in this code. It should be eliminated, not moved.

Comment: Right. But the deadlock point is valid

Comment: I have removed __syncthreads(). Still I am getting wrong results. It is working fine if the height and width of the matrix C is equal. For example, in the case of A[34, 45] x B[45, 34] = C[34, 34], I am getting correct results. But, It is failing in the case of A[34, 45] x B[45, 51] = C[34, 51].

Comment: @user1921237: Answer edited. see last part :)

Comment: Was my answer correct? If it was helpful, please accept/ up it :)

Comment: @user1921237: Please let me know if you found my answer helpful. I think it is basic courtesy

Comment: @Programmer..Thanks a lot..I have removed syncthreads_. And, I have changed Grid dimensions as - dim3 dimGrid((dimBlock.x + numCColumns-1)/dimBlock.x, (dimBlock.y + numARows - 1)/dimBlock.y); Now it is working fine.